# Cant Format Seagate Expansion External Drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I bought a new Seagate External Hard drive. I did a format before starting to transfer my files. but during the format the power cut out due to power shortage here in our place. When power comes back I checked my external again. it tells me that the external needs to format but I am not able to format it using the normal format. Disk management freezes when the external is connected, I also tried to format it using diskpart but when I am in the "clean" part my hard drive disconnects. is there someone here experienced the same? how you resolved it. please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk seems to have died out because of the sudden power cut, or perhaps the power
cut was preceded by a power surge that fried some weak component inside the disk.

This is not a normal behavior for a hard disk, that is supposed to be more resilient
to power cuts or small surges.

I would suggest to return the disk as being defective (no need to mention power
problems) and ask for a replacement or reimbursement.

On the other hand, if your house or area is prone to power problems, I would suggest
to put your equipment behind a power-surge protector or even a (costlier) UPS.

Comment: The External drive is being detected by hard disk sentinel.. but when i try to format it will get disconnected

Comment: and i do get "parameter is incorrect" error when i try to format the external drive

Comment: The problem is with the disk, not with Windows. A bad disk cannot be fixed except by the manufacturer, who will anyway just replace the disk. You can't fix the disk yourself.

Comment: Okay Thanks a lot